# Mongodb Atlas EConnRefused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm testing a feature in my app (I can provide code but it may not be necessary, you'll see) involving pushing data to the backend (mongoose, mongodb atlas cloud server).

I will literally change nothing in my code that has to deal with the data, yet suddenly my app breaks nonstop with the following:

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

[1] Proxy error: Could not proxy request /users/user/5fac1792971d714020531fcf from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.

[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

Anyone have experience with this?

I didn't just post here right away.  I tried solutions from [Error at connecting to MongoDb Atlas Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894913/error-at-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-server)

but nothing was relevant.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, nevermind.  I found the problem.

In my test data, there's a user whose `_id` property for some reason changes to `id`.

This breaks my app until I restart the server.

I don't know why that happens every so often.