# Cannot connect to mongo-atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am trying set up a connection with mongo-atlas but its throwing a connection error

Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectionString = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@nodeexpressproject1.euk9ons.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

mongoose
    .connect(connectionString)
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to the DB.....'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

<username  and <password are my username and password, respectively.

The error shown is:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [ac-i4mxecj-shard-00-00.euk9ons.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: bad auth : authentication failed
```

I have tried basic troubleshooting such as checking IP address

I have checked the following question and no solution works for me
[Error at connecting to MongoDb Atlas Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894913/error-at-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-server)

Please note that I don't have any special characters in my password

Answer (score 0):

Here is your connectionString in place of < username> and < password>, put your username and password, whatever you created at the time of database creation.
Your error also says the same "MongoError: bad auth : authentication failed".

Ex. -
mongodb+srv://ucode:ucode123@nodeexpressproject1.euk9ons.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority