# How to connect to mongoDB Atlas from a deployed application in google cloud?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, google-cloud-platform

I have created an express server that adds users to mongoDB. On local host it works fine. However when I deployed it to google cloud it doesn't add anything to the database. So I believe that I need to configure my `connection.js` differently. Here is the code that I am using:

connection.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/../../../.env' });

const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://' + process.env.DBUSER + ':' + process.env.DBPASSWD + process.env.CLUSTER + '.mongodb.net/' +
    process.env.DB + '?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

const dbOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}

const connectToDatabase = async () => {
    mongoose.connect(dbURI, dbOptions)
        .then(result => console.log("Database connected"))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
};

module.exports = connectToDatabase;
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const handlebars = require("handlebars");
const connectToDatabase = require('./Connection/dbConnection.js');
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/./../../.env' })

connectToDatabase();

const app = express();

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('', require('./routes/routes.js'));

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs.engine({
    defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App listening port ${PORT}`));
```

And here is what I tried to do to make the deployed app work:

1. I created a `env_variables.yaml` and I added the needed connection variables in it as follow:

```
env_variables:
  KEY = 'random-String-here'
  DBUSER = 'mondodb-atlas-username'
  DBPASSWD = 'mondodb-atlas-password'
  DB = 'database name'
  CLUSTER = '@cluster123.example'
```

2. in the `app.yaml` I have :

```
includes:
  - env_variables.yaml

runtime: nodejs20
```

3. and then I modified the `connection.js` as:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fs = require('fs');

// Check if the app is deployed by looking for a deployment-specific environment variable
const isDeployed = process.env.DEPLOYED === 'true';

// Function to load environment variables
const loadEnvVariables = () => {
  if (isDeployed) {
    // Use env_variables.yaml when deployed
    const yaml = require('js-yaml');
    const envVarsYaml = fs.readFileSync('env_variables.yaml', 'utf8');
    const envVars = yaml.safeLoad(envVarsYaml);
    return envVars;
  } else {
    // Use .env when running locally
    require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/../../../.env' });
    return process.env;
  }
};

const env = loadEnvVariables();

const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://' + env.DBUSER + ':' + env.DBPASSWD + env.CLUSTER + '.mongodb.net/' +
    env.DB + '?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

const dbOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
};

const connectToDatabase = async () => {
  mongoose.connect(dbURI, dbOptions)
    .then(result => console.log("Database connected"))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};

module.exports = connectToDatabase;
```

Of course this solution didn't work. Every time I try to add a user I get `Server side error creating a user` Even if I am explicitly using the environment variables values in the `dbURI`. So I am wondering what is the approach that I need to do so that If I am working in development the code uses the `dotevn` file and if the app is deployed it uses the `env_variable` file to connect to the database. But maybe the the verification for production and development isn't needed since `mongoDB Atlas` is hosted online?

First time deploying an app and first time using `Google Cloud`. Any help would be much apprecitaed!

Comment: I would like to confirm if you're deploying your app in App Engine. If so, have you tried adding [your IP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/outbound-ip-addresses) to your [IP Access List](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/#configure-ip-access-list-entries) at MongoDB Atlas side? According to this [post](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-from-google-app-engine/219934) It is a security feature and MongoDB Atlas only allows client connections from entries in the project's IP access list.

Comment: It could also be a matter of whitelisting. Checkout [setting up](https://hevodata.com/learn/mongodb-atlas-nodejs/#:~:text=a%20new%20cluster.-,Step%202%3A%20Add%20User%20and%20Whitelist%20IP%20address,-Once%20you%20have) MongoDB Atlas with NodeJS. Also, check out this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894913/error-at-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-server).

Comment: Yes I am deploying my app in App Engine.  How can I find the IP from there?

Comment: Yeah the issue happened to be from the IP list in ´mongoDB´ as you suggested. I had to add access from elsewhere too. Thanks alot.

Comment: Great! let me know if adding your IP to the access list solved your problem.

Comment: I had my own IP there, however I needed to allow other IPs too, to access the `mongodb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved by adding the App Engine's Outbound IP address as well as OP's other IPs to the IP Access List at MongoDB Atlas. It is a security feature of MongoDB Atlas to only allow connections from entries in the Project's IP access list.

References:

- [Outbound IP addresses for App Engine services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/outbound-ip-addresses)
- [Configure IP Access List Entries](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/#configure-ip-access-list-entries)
- [How to connect to MongoDB Atlas from Google App Engine](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-from-google-app-engine/219934)